# Prevent DTU exhaustion when creating a new index

Tags: azure-sql-database

We're using Azure SQL as a single database and under the DTU pricing model. We have a table with ~50M records, and we'd like to add a new non-clustered index on a single string attribute.

The problem is that this is a production database. If I were to use the simple TSQL syntax of

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IndexName]
ON [dbo].[TableName]([FieldName] ASC);
GO
```

The index creation will peg DTUs to 100% for several minutes, which essentially starves any queries from our application code.

Is there a way in Azure SQL to instruct SQL Server "Hey, only use X DTUs for this indexing operation"?

Comment: Also consider scaling up temporarily to do the deployment and scale back down afterwards.  Or do it at night.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a window of unavailability when scaling between service tiers making that strategy impractical for really large DBs. Also, more DTUs just means that there's more power to perform the indexing, but DTUs will still spike to 100%. That will just shorten the window of unavailability.

Comment: "...but DTUs will still spike to 100%" - you've tried this?  What's your normal DTU (and tier), what did you try at?  This is useful diagnostic information!  For example, I find it hard to believe an index build on a Standard S0 would also flatline DTU at S3, but maybe you've tried.  It's probably worth mentioning that there is a boundary according to the docs: "Important.  The Standard S0, S1 and S2 tiers provide less than one vCore (CPU). For CPU-intensive workloads, a service tier of S3 or greater is recommended."   This is kind of what I'm getting at - make sense?

Comment: Quote above from here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits-single-databases#standard-service-tier

Comment: Oh yes - before making any serious changes to our production DB, we create a copy of it and test our changes via scripting. The indexing of a uniqueidentifier attribute in a table with ~50 million rows on an S7 800 DTU instance pegs DTUs at 100% for four minutes with no other queries interacting on the DB.

Comment: Ah, sorting guids.  That is the root cause of your problem; they're wide, random, prone to fragmentation etc.  Consider integer keys instead.  OK, sometimes it's just the way with third party software.  Re MAXDOP = 1, did you test this out?  As it didn't bear out in my tests on S8/S9 with 33 million row table.  Interested in your results.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use option [MAXDOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to limit the number of processors used.

```
ALTER INDEX test_idx on test_table REBUILD WITH (ONLINE=ON, MAXDOP=1, RESUMABLE=ON) ;
```

You may consider using the Resumable Online Index Rebuild feature so you can schedule X executions of one minute of those indexes.

```
ALTER INDEX [ix_CustomerIDs]
ON [ContosoSales].[ConstosoTransactionData]
REBUILD
WITH (ONLINE = ON, RESUMABLE = ON, MAX_DURATION = 1 MINUTES);
GO

ALTER INDEX ix_CustomerIDs ON [ContosoSales].[ConstosoTransactionData] PAUSE

ALTER INDEX ix_CustomerIDs ON [ContosoSales].[ConstosoTransactionData] RESUME
```

Comment: Thanks! Under the DTU pricing model, I have no idea how many CPUs are allocated to my SQL Server instance since the underlying hardware is hidden from us. Is using MAXDOP just a "trial and error" setting under the DTU model in regards to how many DTUs are consumed?

Comment: Use maxdop = 1. That is the lowest amount of CPU resource you can use.

Comment: I have run the same experiment with the "with (MAXDOP = 1, ONLINE = ON)" on an 800 DTU Azure SQL instance that is a copy of production. No other queries were interacting with the database during the indexing operation. Query completion time for the indexing operation rose to 11:45 in duration, and DTUs still pegged to nearly 100%. So it appears that MAXDOP = 1 is insufficient to prevent DTU exhaustion at 800 DTU. I am reporting this here in case anyone else runs across this same issue.

Comment: Use with these parameters also (ONLINE = ON, RESUMABLE = ON, MAX_DURATION = 1 MINUTES) then use RESUME one minute or 2 later

Comment: Do PAUSE and RESUME 6 times. Allow a few minutes between PAUSE and RESUME to reduce the impact.

Comment: I scaled up to Premium P6 (1000 DTU) from Standard S6 (400 DTU) and rebuilt multiple 5GB+ indexes using "WITH (MAXDOP = 1, ONLINE = ON)" on a production database and was only hitting 50-80% max compute utilisation along. YMMV.